# Unable to get Jamspell to work on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, spell-checking, python-3.7

[Jamspell](https://github.com/bakwc/JamSpell) is an excellent spell checking algorithm which allows the spell checker to be trained on particular models before it can be used. I am having some troubles running it on windows. On Linux it is working fine.

The procedure for installation on windows is a bit involved. First you have to install [Swig](http://www.swig.org/download.html), also you need to have [Microsoft Visual Studios build tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159). It is recommended 2015, however, 2017 also works somewhat.

This was the prerequisites before

`pip install jamspell`

worked with the following status.

`Collecting jamspell
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/16/0a808e926a835604007066085cb2183b337694a06240a99945b31fa14f27/jamspell-0.0.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: jamspell
  Running setup.py install for jamspell ... done
  Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for jamspell from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/16/0a808e926a835604007066085cb2183b337694a06240a99945b31fa14f27/jamspell-0.0.11.tar.
gz#sha256=6dcaf1ae631af6c0904f9ba016bf2404e930237eb73e4d471ee92a77327af8f1
Successfully installed jamspell`

Once this is imported into the code, it is seen that, any model trained on linux is unable to be loaded using this module. The code is stuck infinitely in

`corrector = jamspell.TSpellCorrector()
corrector.LoadLangModel("en.bin")`

However, through experimentation it was found that any model trained on Windows can be loaded into Windows. However, the model is incapable of any corrections, although it provides suggestions.

Examples

`corrector.FixFragment("appel")
appel`

`corrector.GetCandidates("An apple a day keeps the doctor away".split(), 1)
('apple', 'apples', 'appln', 'apply', 'pple', 'appe', 'appel', 'appli', 'applie', 'ample', 'appl', 'appre')`

`corrector.FixFragment("sherluck")
sherluck`

#### Python Version 3.7.

Having unsuccessful in this attempt, I tried to check the python files which were installed for Jamspell, only the following files were present

__pycache__, EGG-INFO, _jamspell.cp37-win_amd64.pyd, _jamspell.py, jamspell.py

Next I tried to look into the files in the github, there was the file jamspell.py which had only information about python 2.

Seeing there was no mention of Python 3, I decided to retry with python 2. For which I had to install [Microsoft Visual Studios C++ Compiler for Python 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266).

After that, trying to install via pip again gave me the following error message

`error: command 'C:\\Users\\Saurav\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

What do I do next?